# Add woocommerce variation description to product name in cart and also for order exports

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was able to add the product variation description to cart and show it on the product page when selected, however, I really need to change the name of the product once the variation is selected (if possible) so that when it shows in cart and/or is exported the product name itself reflects the variations. This particular product has 4 attributes and a total of 448 variations the product is here: https://kmshooting.com/product/custom-diameter-expand-mandrel-selector/

THis is really the only product in the catalog I'd like to do this for.

Here is the code I used to add the variation description to show on product page and in cart but I really need to append to the product name if possible:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'cart_variation_description', 20, 
3);
function cart_variation_description( $name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
// Get the corresponding WC_Product
$product_item = $cart_item['data'];

if(!empty($product_item) && $product_item->is_type( 'variation' ) ) {
    // WC 3+ compatibility
    $descrition = version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ? 
$product_item->get_variation_description() : $product_item- 
>get_description();
    $result = __( '', 'woocommerce' ) . $descrition;
    return $name . $result;
} else
    return $name;
}
```

Comment: With the nuances of Wordpress development, plugins like WooCommerce, and the appropriate use of filters, I wonder if you wouldn't get better responses to this on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ or on a forum specific to the woocommerce platform?